# Need to Update EF Core Tools

Tags: entity-framework-core

When I use the dotnet ef tools in the VS 2017 Package Manager Console I get a warning message about needing to update EF Core tools:

```
PM> dotnet ef migrations list -s ../RideMonitorSite

The EF Core tools version '2.1.1-rtm-30846' is older than that of the runtime '2.1.2-rtm-30932'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes.
20180831043252_Initial
```

But my csproj file has this entry:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I've confirmed that the version installed is, in fact, out of date:

```
PM> dotnet ef --version
Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools
2.1.1-rtm-30846
```

So what do I do to update the tools? BTW, I've seen in other answers that an out of date global.json file can cause this problem. But I don't have a global.json file anywhere in the solution.

Comment: I think you can remove the reference to DotNetCliToolReference, https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/708

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion, @AntonioCampagnaro. But when I remove those references, I still get the warning message.

Comment: Upgrade it by the Package Manager Console like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52770054/1231657)

Answer (score 596, accepted):

Use command line, *Cmd* or *PowerShell* for **specific** version:

`dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version 3.1.0`

or for **latest** version use *(works also for reinstallation)*:

`dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef`

Comment: I had version 3.0.0 and first command worked for me, but second one didn't. When running the command whitout specifying any version i got the following error: 
Tool 'dotnet-ef' failed to update due to the following:
The tool package could not be restored ...

Comment: Why can't they just put this **IN** the error message!

Comment: we should probably make a pr one day... @Simon_Weaver

Comment: The heck, I've created a PR: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/20792

Comment: In my case, updating to the latest version wasn't working. But from the error message I could get the information I had to update from 3.1.6 to **5.0.2**, so I used the specific update `dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version 5.0.2` you suggested, and that succeeded. Thanks! ;-)

Comment: Worked for me :)

Answer (score 27):

for .NET 6, it would be

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version 6.0.0
```

Comment: For my latest version ```dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version 6.0.1```

Comment: Why are you putting version numbers in the command? Just run: dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef    and that's it.

Answer (score 21):

I bounced this issue over to the [development team over on github](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/7422#event-1821659992). Turns out this is a [known issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/releases/tag/2.1.3#known-issues) in the current tooling or nuget packages that get loaded when you create an EF Core-powered AspNet Core site. It's targeted to be fixed in a future release.

For now, the workaround is simply to ignore the warning.

Another workaround is also offered, involving tweaking the csproj file to define the version of the AspNet Core metapackage explicitly -- it's up to 2.1.3 as I'm writing this -- but I couldn't get that approach to work; I still kept getting the warning message.

Answer (score 18):

The solution that worked for me is running the following commands in Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 2.1.11
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 2.1.11
```

Make sure the version matches the one in the error message in my case I got the following error:

```
The EF Core tools version '2.1.1-rtm-30846' is older than that of the runtime '2.1.11-servicing-32099'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes.
```

Check the versions available from the following site:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/

Answer (score 16):

Try this one:
**Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools**

If problem still occurs, then execute this also:
**Update-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools**

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but did not fix the _problem_ for me.

Comment: Installed a missing package for me, solved one generation problem, but the warning persists. Either way good suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

My solution was to install the tool dotnet-ef from microsoft https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-ef. It uses the same commands but no warnings. The change is to use dotnet-ef instead of dotnet ef.

And if you already have dotnet-ef installed then use
`dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version n.n.n` (n.n.n your version to update to)

Answer (score 4):

## To Solve This Issue You May Follow One Of The Following Techniques:

---

- **Technique 1:**  Using Package Manager Console(Especially for Microsoft Visual Studio user) 
   **PM**> `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 2.1.2`
- **Technique 2:** Using **.NET CLI** 
   > `dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools --version 2.1.2`
- **Technique 3:**  Using Package Reference

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.2">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

- **Technique 4:** Using **Packet CLI** 
   > `paket add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools --version 2.1.2`

> **Remember:** For this version to use you need *NuGet 3.6 or higher.* 
> **Reference Link:** ***https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/2.1.2***

Answer (score 2):

Install a new .NET Core SDK v2.1.401 version and check >dotnet ef --version again. I had the same issue and in my case, that worked. Also, you don't need to add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet.

Comment: Thanx, @surbaniak. I'd already done that. It turns out this is a known issue with the current nuget packages, and is targeted for getting fixed. The workaround is to just ignore the issue, as (purportedly; haven't checked this myself) there's no loss of functionality.

Comment: This answer helped also me. I installed .NET Core SDK v2.1.403 (almost the same version) and the warning did not show up anymore. You need to make sure that both the .Net core SDK and runtime is updated to avoid such warning, that the versions are up to date. Urls are changed also at Microsoft web site, but I used: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.1

Comment: I installed .NET Core SKD v2.1.701 (dotnet-sdk-2.1.701-win-x64.exe) but I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

- Ignore the issue
- Do not update your < PackageReference Include = " Microsoft . EntityFrameworkCore . Tools " Version ="" / >
- In my case, I moved forward with 'Update-Database -Context MyElementContext' and now it is all working fine.

I found this in the book 'Programming ASP.NET Core' by Dino Esposito.

'Note This version of the CLI tooling is not the same as the version of the .NET Core runtime the application will use. The runtime version is speciﬁed in the project ﬁle, and you can comfortably edit it from within the user interface of the IDE of your choice. If you want, instead, to edit the project ﬁle manually, then it is as easy as editing the .csproj XML ﬁ le and changing the value of the TargetFramework element. The value refers to the moniker that identiﬁes the version (such as netcoreapp2.0).'

Answer (score 1):

Like Martin
Use command line, Cmd or PowerShell for specific version:

dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version 3.1.0

or for latest version use (works also for reinstallation):

dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef

But, I've got probleme in my pc : 
"When running the command whitout specifying any version i got the following error: Tool 'dotnet-ef' failed to update due to the following: The tool package could not be restored" Liko Pippo46

So, I use these steps :

> dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-ef
>   But got the same problem, so I'm going to the directory of the extension : 
>   C:\Users\Evan.dotnet\tools.store\dotnet-ef

And I found the old version (2.x)
And my second problem was the file fileproject.assets.json was not found

So I copy the fileproject.assets.json in the 2.x version to the parent repository

And all was done perfectly :

1. dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-ef

   > removes the 2.x version
2. dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef

   > install the 3.1 one

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find how to update the package specifically, but in the Package Manager Console I ran 'update-package'. It ran through and updated all packages referenced in a project, including the EF Core Tools. That may not be ideal for you as that could update packages you didn't want.

Comment: Thanx, @malckier. I ran update-package, and it updated some stuff. But the warning message still appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps in this document helped me solve the problem - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-net-en/connector-net-entityframework-core-scaffold-example.html

**Scaffolding a Database Using Package Manager Console in Visual Studio**

- Open Visual Studio and create a new Console App (.NET Core) for C#.
- Add the MySQL NuGet package for EF Core using the Package Manager Console. For example, use the following command to add the MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore v8.0.13 package:

> Install-Package MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 8.0.13

**Important**

The version (for example, -Version 8.0.13) must match the actual Connector/NET version you are using. For current version information.

- Install the following NuGet packages by selecting either Package
  Manager Console or Manage NuGet Packages for Solution from the Tools
  and then NuGet Package Manager menu:

  ```
  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

  EF Core 1.1 only: Also add the MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Design package.

  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools version 1.1.6 (for EF Core 1.1) and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools version 2.0.3 (for EF Core 2.0)
  Note

  The .NET tools are included in the .NET Core 2.1 SDK and not required or supported for EF Core 2.1. If this is an upgrade, remove the reference to that package from the .csproj file (version 2.0.3 in this example) :

  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.3" />
  ```

  Open **Package Manager Console** and enter the following command at the prompt to create the entities and `DbContext` for the `sakila` database (adjust the connection-string values to match your settings for the user= and password= options):

> Scaffold-DbContext "server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=mypass;database=sakila"
>   MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir sakila -f

Visual Studio creates a new sakila folder inside the project, which contains all the tables mapped to entities and the sakilaContext.cs file.

*Even though the Oracle instructions said that Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools was not needed for EF Core 2.1 I installed the version 2.2.0 that is compatible with EF 2.2*

Answer (score 0):

Update EF Core tools using *dotnet CLI* or *Package Manager Console* or visiting 
this site https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/2.1.2

 
Or you may ignore this. It's not a big issue...

Answer (score 0):

In your application, Dot.net core library version is 2.1.2 and you are working on 2.1.1 of Entity framework core(2.1.1).
So, Update your library version which should be equal to dot.net core version (2.1.2).

Answer (score -1):

I got this error multiple times my packages was up to date in NuGet package manager
So I modified (.csproj) with note pad to the desired version and it solved my problem.

Comment: You shouldn't do that let alone recommend it. Almost all of the answers here have better solutions that should also have worked in your case.