# How to upgrade EF Core Tools

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

When I `add-migration` i got this warning:

```
The EF Core tools version '2.1.1-rtm-30846' is older than that of the runtime '2.1.4-rtm-31024'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes.
```

I haven't found any information how can I update this, except with updating DotNET Core SDK, but this hasn't worked for me.

Comment: Update your project's entity framework core packages to 2.1.4.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Its version is 2.1.4 already but the problem still exists

Comment: oh! Have your tried after deleting the bin folder?

Comment: The tools are included in the EF Core NuGet package.

Comment: @TanvirArjel I have tried to delete the bin folder, but the problem still ocures

Comment: @ChrisPratt  My Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore NuGet package is at version 2.1.4

Comment: Then something else isn't right. Clean, rebuild, restart Visual Studio, delete bin and obj directories and rebuild, etc.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. It happened right after I installed the NuGet package IdentityServer4.EntityFramework

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51284974/ef-core-tools-version-update-2-1-1

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Update the tools using the package manager console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 2.1.4
```

see this link https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/

Comment: I feel like an idiot asking and thank you because this has worked - but, why doesn't this show up when looking for updates in Nuget?

Comment: This solution worked, whereas the `dotnet tool update...` solution did not, regardless if I executed the command in the NuGet Package Manager Console or from the Windows Terminal.

Answer (score 59):

If you are using a command line ( CMD, Powershell, bash etc ) you can easily type the following to update into the latest version:

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef
```

If you want to update into a very specific version do the following:

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version VERSION_NUMBER
```

Example:

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version 3.1.0
```

Answer (score 4):

To piggyback on [daniel-chikaka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59484154/3768875)'s solution, if you are still seeing the error after running the update command for the global environment.

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef
```

Try removing the `--global` parameter so that it updates the **dotnet-tools.json** file associated with the project.

```
dotnet tool update dotnet-ef
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue: This issue I was getting: The Entity Framework tools version '5.0.2' is older than that of the runtime '7.0.1'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes. See https://aka.ms/AAc1fbw for more information.

Tried the following solutions:

1. installed updated dotnet ed version with dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 7.0.1 [Same error]
2. installed the dotnet ef version with adding source dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 7.0.1 --add-source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json  [Same error]
3. Tried to uninstall the dotnet ef version by using dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-ef and then installed the 7.0.1 version using dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 7.0.1 --add-source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json  [Same error]
4. Also tried to ignore issues by using install -g dotnet-ef --version 5.0.2 --ignore-failed-sources  [Same error]
5. Finally the solution that helped was to remove the dotnet-ef cache and installing by using dotnet tool update --no-cache dotnet-ef --version 7.0.1 --ignore-failed-sources [The removed 5.0.2 version from cache and used 7.0.1 version of dotnet ef]